# is it necessary that we should be enrolled in apple developer memebership to use sirikit?

Tags: sirikit

I want to check Sirikit integration.
Is it necessary that we should be enrolled in apple developer membership to use Sirikit? Without enrollment how to use sirikit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to be enrolled to paid Apple developer account to use SiriKit. You can't use it without paid apple developer account